# Apply coordinate system to 3D model

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I have a [GLTF 3D model of planet earth](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/low-poly-planet-earth-e54e860710ac4102ad5d57609a5b52b9). I'm currently trying to add points to this model representing coordinates made of longitude and latitude. It works fine when I'm not using a custom 3D model, but a `SphereGeometry` with an earth texture. I use the following function to calc the coordinate's position:

```
export const latLonToRad = (lat: number, lon: number, radius: number): Vector3 => {
    const phi = (90 - lat) * (Math.PI / 180);
    const theta = (lon + 180) * (Math.PI / 180);

    const x = -(radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta));
    const z = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
    const y = radius * Math.cos(phi);

    return new Vector3(x, y, z);
};
```

This function worked for the sphere, but not for the custom 3D model. How so? Is it wrong dimensions? Can I even calculate the correct position for such a custom 3D model? Do I need to set some kind of initial state to fit the correct dimensions for the actual world's coordinate system?